# Extending a WebControl using a partial class

Tags: c#, inheritance, web-controls

Is is possible to extend, for instance, the HyperLink control using a partial class?

I'd like to define some custom properties on the control, without having to extend the class... like so...

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" CustomPropertyA="a" CustomPropertyB="b" />
```

And be able to use them on OnInit/OnPreload etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Partial types *only* allow you to specify the code for a type within multiple source files within the same project. That's all. They're a compile-time change only - they don't affect the object model, or what you can do with types which already exist etc.

It sounds like you may just want to create a new class *derived* from `HyperLink` instead.

Answer (score 2):

As Jon said, you have to create a new class derived from HyperLink. But if you are after to keep the old tag structure, use [tag mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164641.aspx) as well.